# How to execute foxpro 2.6(DOS) commands from C# that needs exclusive access to table?

Tags: c#, oledb, foxpro

This is my code, and I want to delete all the data of the FoxPro tables named as SMS_DATA, I tried **ZAP** command, as well as also tried **DELETE ALL** and **PACK** command with the **USE** -table-name, but it doesn't working, and gives the exception that:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): File must be opened exclusively.
```

This is my code:

```
     string USETBL ="EXECSCRIPT([USE SMS_DATA && Open SMS_DATA table])";
     string DELETE="EXECSCRIPT([DELETE ALL])";       
     string PACK="EXECSCRIPT([PACK])";

                       OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                       try
                       {

                           OleDbCommand cmd  = new OleDbCommand(USETBL, con);
                           OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(DELETE, con);
                           OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(PACK, con);

                           con.Open();
                           err.log("connection opened");
                           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           err.log("table in use");
                           cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           err.log("delete executed.");
                           cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           err.log("pack executed.");
                           con.Close();
                       }
                       catch (Exception e)
                       {
                           err.log("Exception:-" + e);
                       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line should be:

```
EXECSCRIPT([USE SMS_DATA EXCLUSIVE && Open SMS_DATA table]);
```

for safety I would also change the next two lines to:

```
string DELETE="EXECSCRIPT([DELETE ALL IN SMS_DATA])";       
string PACK="EXECSCRIPT([PACK IN SMS_DATA])";
```

Comment: I have now replaced the DELETE and PACK commands with single ZAP command, bcoz its much faster and we don't need to use two commands for deletion, but thanks a lot..

Comment: Yeah either will work. ZAP has considerations where table or database triggers won't fire where they would with DELETE\PACK but I'm guessing that is not a problem in your case.